# How should I use Firestore to make a dynamic view with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have no goal of dynamically updating the screen without restarting the application. But even so, I cannot do it. First, the screen is shown, and then the data is requested from the database
So, i see the empty view. Maybe i can’t fully understand how the threads are working and problem is here

I wanna use info from the Firestore in my view

```
struct Exercises: View {

@ObservedObject private var viewModel = ExViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(viewModel.exData) { exData in
                if exData.isShow {
                    NavigationLink(destination: CarouselView(navBarTitle: exData.name, data: exData.cards, dataIds: exData.cardsId)) {
                        ButtonView(title: exData.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        AdBannerView()
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Упражнения")
    .onAppear(){
        self.viewModel.fetchData()
        
    }
}
}
```

And here how i get my data

```
class ExViewModel: ObservableObject{
@Published var exData = [ExercisesData]()

private var db = Firestore.firestore()

func fetchData() {
    let rootCollection = db.collection("exercises")

    var ex : [ExercisesData] = []
    
    
    rootCollection.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            
                let name = document.data()["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let isShow = document.data()["isShow"] as? Bool ?? false
                let cardsId = document.data()["cardsId"] as? [String] ?? []
                                    
                ex.append(ExercisesData(id: document.documentID, name: name, isShow: isShow, cardsId: cardsId))
                
            }  
        }
        self.exData = ex
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with init() or threads. I don’t now that I need to add this object to SceneDelegate. So, i just need to add .environmentObject(ExViewModel()) to my main view

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: MotherView().environmentObject(ExViewModel()))
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That class doesn't have an `init()` at all - so the `fetchData()` function isn't actually getting called.

Try adding

```
init() {
    self.fetchData()
}
```